# Delphi Tchart leftaxis time labels

Tags: delphi, teechart

I would like to use a TChart to evaluate times. (like 1:12; 1:15; 1:13; ...) For this I would like to show the experiments (1,2,3 ...) on the X-axis. The Y-axis should be a time legend. (as seen in the photo on the X-axis).
Unfortunately, I succeed only on the X-axis.

The time legend I wish on the Y-axis

[image: The time legend I wish on the Y-axis]

**What I tried:**

```
procedure kMyDiagram.config;
Begin
    mychart.LeftAxis.LabelStyle := taltext;
    DataLine:=TLineSeries(MyChart.Series[0]);
end;

procedure kMyDiagram.myDiagramMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer)
begin
    timecounter:=timecounter +10;
    time:=strtotime('00:0'+ timecounter);
    DataLine.AddXY(DataLine.XScreenToValue(x),DataLine.YScreenToValue(y),timetostr(time));
end;
```

This creates something like that...
[image: Time Labels at Y-Axis but also at X-Axis(and there should be integers like 1,2,3...)]

Time Labels at Y-Axis but also at X-Axis(and there should be integers like 1,2,3...)

So how can I make this custom Y-Axis?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Well, then pass `Time` to the first parameter of the `AddXY` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new `TChart` with `TLineSeries`, and made the only setting: `Series1-General-Vertical Axis-DateTime` checkbox.

Now code below produces chart with `0..7` labels on X axis and `0:00, 0:30...7:00` labels on Y axis  (1/24 is one hour)

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 7 do
    Series1.AddXY(i, (i * i) / 7 * 1/24);
```

Comment: Great! It works. Now I have to modify it a littel bit but in general it is what I aspected. I never aspekted the fraction '1/24' as a part of the answer.         First question on 'StackOverlow'. Great community